# Linux program to emulate keystrokes without X

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, keyboard, linux-device-driver, keyboard-events

I'm writing a driver for a pda with a goal of converting UART received key numbers to keystrokes.

The way i currently have this system set up is that when a key number is received, i can exec a program. In a config it is defined what command is executed if a certain number is received by my driver. It does this by `fork()`ing and `exec()`ing. It runs at boot and immediately parses these key numbers, so i intend to use this instead of a real keyboard.

Is there any program then, with which i could simply do something like

`programname KEY_SPACE 1` to press KEY_SPACE

and

`programname KEY_SPACE 0` to release KEY_SPACE?

Such a program must work without, as well as with X. I'd also prefer this to be able to do mouse events as well, however if there is a different program to do that, that's fine by me. It can be run as root as well, if need be.

Comment: Look for `hid-replay` script. https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libevdev/hid-tools/

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use uinput, it allows to emulate input device from userspace. You have documentation here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.11/input/uinput.html
It has an example showing how to send a KEY_SPACE press event and then a KEY_SPACE release event.